# The system is running in low-graphics mode ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

The system is running in low-graphics mode is the message I received after my laptop froze when I upgraded to ubuntun 14.04 I need this sorted been on google search all day and im not winning please help need to get my laptom running

Comment: What video card/chip do you have? Upgrade probably did not reinstall a proprietary driver?

Comment: Instructions on how to gather diagnostic data can be found at [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](/questions/14008/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

When you hit the log on screen type <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to open a tty1 session.

Log in with your username and password.

Type

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

See if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify more on Musher's answer, it is a problem with Ubuntu's default display, as lightdm is being obsolete and unsupported. To fix this press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F1</kbd>  to open a temporary display-lacking terminal. If that doesn't work use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>F3</kbd>  instead. Once there, there are a two options to solve lightdm.

1: Use GDM Instead **RECCOMENDED**

```
 sudo apt-get install gdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Then select GDM and hit  <kbd>Enter.</kbd>

2: Repair LightDm **NOT RECCOMENDED**

```
 sudo apt-get purge lightdm && sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get install lightdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
 sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo shutdown now -r
```